# sendmail 504 Gateway Time-out on laravel homestead

Tags: php, email, laravel, sendmail, homestead

I was coding a web APP using the lumen framework on windows with xampp, but after a few issues with routing and so own, I decided to give homestead and vagrant a try.

I managed to get homestead installed and the routing is working better than xampp, but when I tried to use the mail function from php I found that command sendmail wasn't installed on the homestead virtual machine cause i was getting a 500 internal server error, and with xampp email sending was working just fine. So with shh I did a simple **sudo apt-get install sendmail** to install it. But when now whenever I try to use the mail function from php it just waits and waits and eventually I get a **504 Gateway Time-out**.

What might be happening and what can I do to solve it?

BTW: If you have any suggestions to replace the simple mail function for something else that works I'm willing to try it!

Thank you guys for your time.

This is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomKey!!!

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_FILE=database.sqlite
DB_DATABASE='storage/database.sqlite'
DB_DRIVER=sqlite

CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=[mailtrap_username]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[mailtrap_password]
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally when in development I like to use the `log` driver. This writes any emails sent into the `storage/logs/` log file. I find this more convenient as it totally ensures no mail is accidentally sent when testing.

If you did want to actually send mail then I'd suggest mailgun, its free for 10,000 emails every month and I use this for every app I've built at work. Super quick and convenient, also includes tracking, delivery confirmation, etc.

After you've signed up you'll want to setup a new domain which will give you several credentials you'll need to add to your `config/services.php`, those being your domain and API key.

You'll then need to install guzzle for your application (this is need as mailgun uses a HTTP API to send email, which is much quicker than SMTP and traditional mail transport options).

`composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"`

The final thing would to then be set your mail driver to `mailgun` and you should be well on your way.

Edit: Looking through the config files of `laravel/lumen-framework` doesn't look like its possible to be able to supply the relevant information to be able to use mailgun, or any service that requires information from the `services.php` config file as this isn't included in lumen for some reason.

https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/tree/5.1/config

Comment: I'll try tonight as soon as I arrive home, do you have any tutorial to make mailgun work on lumen?  Thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer, sadly doesn't seem possible out of the box. I'm sure you could probably hack at the config interface to get something going.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try http://mailtrap.io? Its free and is a simple SMTP server to send emails to from PHP which is caught in their simple web interface.

Its really good for testing email sending locally as it will trap the emails so you can view them at your leisure.

As a bonus: Laravel 5 now includes mailtrap as default SMTP settings, letting you just provide username and password :)

Comment: That's what I've been using so far! I have a mailtrap account and with xampp was working just fine, but when I switched to homestead using the same code it just stop working with the timeout error.

Comment: What is in your env file?

Comment: I just edited my question with the .env file, its exaclty the same I had on my xampp setup, so I guess its the VM on vagrant not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using smtp and have email working locally but 504 error on the server, this instruction helps:

> if your website has ssl certificate, change the line `‘encryption’ => ‘tls’` to `’encryption’ => ‘ssl’` and `‘port’ => 465`.